# A network related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server, error 40 - Could

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, firewall

Since I re-installed windows7, visual studio and Sql Server 2008 the same, I can't add a connection to a .mdf.
I have already allowed the 1433 port access in the firewall but the error message remains:

**A network related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. Verify the name instance is correct and that the SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.(provider:Shared Memory Provider, error 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)**

can you please help me?

Comment: When are you receiving the error - from visual studio or from an application

Comment: Can you specify the connection string?

Comment: This is either off-topic (because it's regarding the software re-installs), or you haven't given enough information (the code being used to connect to the DB, what language is being used, is the mdf local or on a network, etc).

Comment: thx! I get the error in visual studio 2010! Even creating a new database, it doesn't work. the server in the combo box is MACHIN_NAME\SQLEXPRESS! and it returns the same error
I'm coding in ASP.NET MVC with C#

Answer (score 2):

we have to give the port number to 1433 as well as [enable the tcp/ip in configuration manager](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ea9f0e79-ef69-4d47-9862-d53a1e460003/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure when connecting to the SQL server, that you have the name of the server (named instance )  same as the one you would see when you connect to the SQL sever when opening the  SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a named instance it won't be on the default port number.  And did your host name change?

Comment: how will I then know the port number that is beeing used? sorry I'm not good with "named instance theory"! 
My hostname??? first my ComputerNAME was BELLASH_HP. SInce i re-installed I changed it into ADABELLASH...

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL Server stopped you can Active SQL Server again by:

1. Go Start
2. Right-click My computer
3. Click Manage
4. Click Service tab left
5. Find SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)
6. Right-Click On SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) then click start

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCHUERKhZi8